# MySQL database connection closed immiately after checking if it's closed

Tags: java, jdbc

I've been doing a ton of work on a java app of mine to increase database connection stability, etc. There's a single problem that still plagues users that seems common enough to be a problem with my code and not their db servers.

We're using jdbc-pool.

The error:

```
Database connection error: Connection has already been closed.
 java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
 at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:118)
 at $Proxy12.commit(Unknown Source)
 at me.botsko.prism.actionlibs.ActionRecorder.insertActionsIntoDatabase(ActionRecorder.java:201)
 at me.botsko.prism.actionlibs.ActionRecorder.save(ActionRecorder.java:81)
 at me.botsko.prism.actionlibs.ActionRecorder.run(ActionRecorder.java:230)
 at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:53)
 at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code it relates to:

```
public void insertActionsIntoDatabase() {

    PreparedStatement s = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        if( !queue.isEmpty() ){

            conn = Prism.dbc();
            if(conn == null || conn.isClosed()){
                // try to re-open conn
                return;
            }
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            s = conn.prepareStatement("QUERY HERE");
            while (!queue.isEmpty()){
                s.executeBatch(); // Execute every x items.
            }

            s.executeBatch();
            conn.commit();

        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        plugin.handleDatabaseException( e );
    } finally {
        if(s != null) try { s.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {}
        if(conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
}
```

I've long had checks for the whether or not the connection was closed, but somehow something skips past that. This code grabs a new pool connection each time it runs so it's not using a connection used by another part of the app.

Comment: What is this line? `org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:53)`

Comment: This is a plugin for a project called bukkit, and that has a system to run tasks async. That's all that is.

Comment: Are these Tomcat managed connections?

Comment: Tomcat isn't involved, only the jdbc-pool package.

Comment: You need to provide your configurations for Tomcat JDBC datasource pool. Because the real cause of the problem must be there.

Comment: It's defined here: https://github.com/prism/Prism/blob/master/src/main/java/me/botsko/prism/Prism.java#L301